# LTSpice "Unknown parameter "\""

Tags: ltspice, equation, data-operator

I am trying to simulate an electrical model (Mason Model) of piezoelectric system in LTSpice. So, I use parameters and formulas to evaluate the value of the passive elements in my circuit.

I use the following eq. for one of my capacitor:

```
C = {Zo}\{cos({Tou}*{t})}
```

which returns an error saying:

```
Error on line 9 : c3 p001 n007  63262.1256016315 \ 0.876872546720567 
 Unknown parameter "\"
```

I also use 1/{f} for calculating the on time of my pulse signal but that seems to work just fine. Am I missing to define a library?

Comment: already tried {1/f}?

Comment: To extend a bit on @Unknown123's comment, why would you use `\\`` *after* trying the normal `/`?

Comment: @Unknown123 1/{f} or {1/f} doesn't show an error but its the expression from C = {Zo}\{cos({Tou}*{t})} is the problem

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen results: 
Error on line 9 : c3 p001 n007  63262.1256016315 / 0.876872546720567 
  Unknown parameter "/"

Error on line 9 : c3 p001 n007  63262.1256016315 \` 0.876872546720567 
  Unknown parameter "\`"

Comment: @Akki Pardon for my indirect explanation. That's not my point actually. I mean you should know when you should wrap all of the equation using curly brackets and when you should not. Read here: [.Param and Curly Brackets](https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Hints_on_using_individual_LTspice_commands_and_things_the_Help_Manual_sometimes_may_not_help_you_with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `\` to a `/` if you want to do division.

As far as I know, `\` has no meaning in LTSpice, so it's not surprising it gives an error message about something being "unknown" when you use this symbol.

**Edit**

Based on comments, the actual problem is that the expression must be surrounded by `{` and `}`.

Comment: Yes, tried changing the symbols. Still the same error ' Unknown parameter "/" '

Comment: @Akki, did you try wrapping the whole thing in `{` and `}`?

Comment: Yes, That worked!